# Displaying records in Gridview when particular radio button is selected

Tags: c#, mysql

I am developing a web portal using the ASP.NET framework in C# with a MySQL database server. My problem is that in one page there are 4 radio buttons (SAP Info, DB info, OS info and License Info) and one grid view.

I want to know how to display records in a single grid view when any one radio button is selected. For example, if I select the SAP info button, the info about SAP should be displayed in grid view from database. Similarly, if I select OS info button then info about OS should be displayed in grid view and same for other 2 buttons. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a forum for asking for code. This site is for getting answers to specific programming problems, so post some code which you have tried and are having problems with and we will help to solve the problem, we are not just going to do you work for you however. Have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more information on what type of questions are expected on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When u click any of your radio button, go to your db and get the specific data (according to your checked radio button) and than bind your grid again from the new data source.
It is good approach to use the stored procedure and pass a parameter of @InfoType with datatype tinyint or int.

**Edited:**
add the row command event like that

`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">`

and in your c# code create an event like that

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);



       textbox1.Text = GridView1.Rows[index]["UserID"].value.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Its better that you should try some code yourself and than share with us, if there is any problem in your code than the people will help u out..

Comment: Hey Talha, please help me with my another question.

Comment: I have one gridview in that there are 4 columns namely "User ID","Description","Display Password","Change Password". I have put an Image Button in Change Password Column for each cell. Below the Gridview there are 3 text boxes. When I click on Change Password, the User ID of that particular row should be displayed in text box 1. How to do this in asp.net with C# and back end is MySql DB server.

Comment: read my answer again, i have updated it, read the Edited portion

Comment: Hi Talha, <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"> in this which DataSource I have to write? and also in  textbox1.Text = GridView1.Rows[RowIndex]["UserID"].value.ToStrin();  the RowIndex should be generic, I want to get the value of only that row whose change pwd image button is clicked..

Comment: remove DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  and do wat u r already doing... and on GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) event, use the e.RowIndex property. as mentioned in the answer

Comment: after typing "e" it is not suggesting RowIndex option. so i think there is some mistake.

Comment: int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); by using this you can get the index

Comment: <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvPassInfo" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" DataKeyNames="user_id" CssClass="Gridview"  OnRowEditing="gvPassInfo_RowEditing" OnRowCommand="gvPassInfo_RowCommand" > <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Change Password">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtnChangePass" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/PW.jpg" CausesValidation="false"
CommandName="Edit" />
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField> tis is my .aspx file

Comment: protected void gvPassInfo_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {if (e.CommandName == "change")
        {panelChangePassword.Visible = true;
            //txtUserid.Text = gvPassInfo.Rows[RowIndex]["UserID"].value.ToString();
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use onselectedindexchanged event of radiobuttonlist and there you bind the data on selection change. Put all the design or gridview in update panel so that full page will not postback. Use asyncPostbacktrigger. You can cache the data instead of binding every time. If not in cache or cache expires bring data from data source.